# assignment operation in FORALL clause

Tags: oracle, plsql, forall

I am trying to use an INSERT statement with a FORALL clause after some variable calculations.

More exactly:

```
declare
    type t_test_bis is table of test_1%rowtype;
    v_test_bis t_test_bis;

    cursor c_1 is
        select * from test_1;
    i number;
begin

    OPEN c_1;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_1 BULK COLLECT INTO v_test_bis;     
        EXIT WHEN c_1%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_1;

    forall j in 1 .. v_test_bis.count
        v_test_bis(i).age := v_test_bis(i).age + 10;  -- is there a way to perform such opperation?
        insert into test_2 values v_test_bis(i);

end;
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, because FORALL statement may contain just a single DML statement, while you have two of them (if that's what you ask).

Answer (score 2):

`forall` binds a collection to a single SQL statement and executes it, all in one shot. It's not a loop, and there is no facility to inject any per-row processing steps.

Instead, you can code a separate step to loop through the collection and modify each value prior to the `forall`.